# how to sum database value in Inner join?

Tags: mysql

[myoutput.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nun8Y.png)

```sql
SELECT new_arrival.Date_arrival,
       new_arrival.Expiry_date,
       new_arrival.Batch_No, 
       SUM(distribution.Quantity_in_Dose) AS doses, 
       SUM(new_arrival.dose) AS dose
FROM new_arrival 
LEFT JOIN distribution on new_arrival.Batch_No = distribution.batch_number 
GROUP BY new_arrival.Date_arrival,
         new_arrival.Expiry_date,
         new_arrival.Batch_No,
         new_arrival.dose
```

```php
  $s_sn = 1;
                          while($Get_bloods =$find_bloods->fetch_assoc())          {
                   
                         
                        $dose = $Get_bloods['dose'];
                         $Date_arrival = $Get_bloods['Date_arrival'];
                         $Date_arrival = date("F d, Y", strtotime($Date_arrival));
                         $Expiry_date = $Get_bloods['Expiry_date'];
                            $Expiry_date = date("F d, Y", strtotime($Expiry_date));
                         $Batch_No = $Get_bloods['Batch_No'];
                          $doses = $Get_bloods['doses'];
                          
                          
                          if (is_null($doses)) {
         $doses = 'No Distribution Found';
      
    } else {
       $doses = $Get_bloods['doses'];
    }
                          
 $total_doses = $dose - $doses;
                  $dose = number_format($dose);
              
                 $total_doses = number_format($total_doses);
?>
```

Comment: I want to sum the value of new_arrival and distribution and subtract it to get result of remaining balance

Comment: And what is the problem? Join multiplying? aggregate `distribution` in subquery then join. PS. You use `new_arrival.dose` in grouping expression, but it absent in the output list - hence you'll receive the rows duplicated by another 3 columns in grouping expression without the possibility to define what `new_arrival.dose` value matches to each separate dup.

Comment: my problem is I cannot get the exact value of my new_arrival_dose. plse click the ,myoutput.jpg  you can view may result there

Comment: Your screenshot tells me nothing. Provide CREATE TABLE for both tables, INSERT INTO with sample data (2-3 arrivals, 2-3 distribution per arrival) and show desired output for this data.

Comment: i want to get the remaining balance. i cannot get the exact value of new_arrival.dose the exact value must be 10,000+ not 2 million

Comment: Create small sample data by hands. *the exact value must be 10,000+ not 2 million* I have said already: "aggregate `distribution` in subquery then join".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need in this or similar:

```sql
SELECT new_arrival.Date_arrival,
       new_arrival.Expiry_date,
       new_arrival.Batch_No, 
       doses.doses, 
       SUM(new_arrival.dose) AS dose
FROM new_arrival 
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT batch_number, COALESCE(SUM(Quantity_in_Dose), 0) AS doses
            FROM distribution 
            GROUP BY batch_number ) doses ON new_arrival.Batch_No = doses.batch_number
GROUP BY new_arrival.Date_arrival,
         new_arrival.Expiry_date,
         new_arrival.Batch_No,
         doses.doses
```